# php fopen function not working through linked script

Tags: php, hyperlink, fopen

Hi I have created a php that creates a file in php using fopen it works fine by itself but when I access it through another php script it fails to create the file.
I tried `sudo chown -R root /directory` on the directory but it doesn't work and `sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_script_rw_t /directory`, but still to no avail.

```
<?php
    $my_file    = '../file.js';
    $handle     = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);

    //check if the file exists
    if (file_exists('../file.js')){
        echo "file exists <br />";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting the "Cannot open file" error or is something else happening?

Comment: the script just fails when it gets to line 3 :$handle =fopen().... but when I run the the script directly it works fine. I dont think the problem is the directory permissions because, the script runs well when accessed directly and I check the php info file to see is all_url_fopen has been set properly and it is.

Comment: try to call the path directly instead of ../file.js try it

Comment: fails? It will typically give you an error message. what is the message?

Comment: @vicky : calling the path directly worked, but I want the script to be easy to move to any other webserver

Comment: Thanks for your help guys and @Pjack I wasn't getting any errors messages my code just seemed to halt on the fopen line.